# simple_html_dom: trying to find height in google search

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom, scrape

Anyone can explain to me what is wrong with the code and how do i get the height value? I am trying to get the height of celebrities. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

My code (Updated with CURL user agent setting as advised):

```
$url='https://www.google.com/webhp?ie=UTF-8#q=ailee+height';

//Set CURL user agent
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//simple html dom
require_once('lib/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html($data);
$height= $html->find('div[class="_eF"]',0)->innertext;
echo $height;
```

I get empty from the above code. In this case, I want to return:

```
5' 5" (1.65 m)
```

Comment: Make sure you set the same user agent in php that you're using to see the page, otherwise the content will be different. Set the UA in curl to fetch the html and then pass it to simple-html-dom.

Comment: I don't know how you came up with that code, but I don't see how you would be able to find a celebritys height programatically with a google search (without a lot more lines than what you are using in your example)

Comment: @Ishas I am using simple html dom to parse the value

Comment: @Pedro Lobito - I have set the UA in curl (as seen by changes above) but it still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `curl` doesn't  process `JavaScript` and Google will show a different webpage when `JavaScript` is disabled, in this case, the `div` changes to a `span` with a different `id`

```
<span class="_m3b">1.65 m</span>
```

Also, the link you were using wasn't working for me.

Try this instead:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$url='https://www.google.pt/search?q=ailee+height&num=10&gbv=1';

//Set CURL user agent
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html($data);
$height= $html->find('span[class="_m3b"]',0)->innertext;
echo $height;
//1.65 m
```

Comment: Thanks, Pedro! I have changed the url to 'https://www.google.com/search?q=ailee+height'  as advised. Without changing my code above and now it works. Maybe my server can't access the original url same like you do.

Comment: You're very welcome @Calvin, GL! Make sure you set the results number to small value, i.e.: `num=10`,  otherwise the page will take longer to load.